# QGIS, place points on polylines by name of the the polyline and linear distance along that polyline from a CSV

Tags: qgis, point, line

I have a CSV file with mileposts for road hazards on named roads, but I do not have coordinates. I have a polyline GeoPackage layer with said roads. The road names on the hazards CSV and road gpk match. Road names are unique, but there are multiple hazards on some roads. Each road has been made into a single polyline. I want to place each hazard at the corresponding milepost as a point with coordinates that can be symbolized.

Update 8/17/2023.
I found a promising plugin called LRS. Here is a tutorial - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cBlWd7sGSOA&t=68s
I found this link with the google search "qgis create point on a line at specified distance"

Comment: @Ammson50 could you add an example of how your csv looks like?

Comment: RoadName CountyNum ObsType MaxHeight MaxWidth Linear Feet MilePost PW_Notes GIS_Notes
CHITWOOD RD 427 Vertical 12 NA 0 0.00E+00  Placed at start of covered bridge to not imply obstructing Crystal Creek Lp

Comment: Last header is GIS_Notes. Then the rest is one line of entries corresponding to the headers.